# how to save information from input box in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, bots

```
dim fname
fname=inputbox("Hi! What's your name?")
fname=inputbox("Thats cool " & fname)
fname=inputbox("so wanna cyber?")
fname=inputbox("What nevermind i change my mind bye!")
```

how do i save the input that the user gives in the input box  in another file ?

for example if the user answers the first inputbox and I need to store its output in variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the file open while writing, only close in the end.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, CreateIfNeeded = true
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set file = fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", ForWriting, CreateIfNeeded)

dim fname 
fname = inputbox("Hi! What's your name?")
file.write fname
file.close
```